# iOS Core Foundation Memory Leak in External Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, core-foundation

I'm currently trying to write an application using an open-source, external library.  I have the source code available to it, and can build myself a fresh copy whenever needed.

Anyway, while profiling my application - I noticed that some memory was leaking in the library. It's small - 128b a shot - but still, I'd prefer *not* to have memory leaks to begin with.

Here's the code.  The modified code that I wrote is on top (that leaks), and the original code is on bottom (that leaks).

```
CFURLRef getURLFromPath(const char * path) {
  //modified code to hopefully clean up after myself
  CFStringRef cfTotalPath = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, path, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
  CFURLRef cURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, cfTotalPath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
  CFRelease(cfTotalPath);

  return cURL;

  //original code
  /*CFStringRef cfTotalPath = CFStringCreateWithCString (kCFAllocatorDefault,
      path, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

  return CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfTotalPath,
      kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);*/

}
```

I'm relatively new to iOS programming; I'm debugging on an actual device, and I know that sometimes Instruments gives false-positives when it comes to leaks.

This is infuriating, because this one block of code is the last step in the stack trace for my leaks... and I honestly do not know how to fix it.

EDIT: From what I've read, Apple doesn't mind the occasional memory leak here and there; I'll continue programming, because this process only happens *once* per music file in my application - analyzing a track for the BPM (it gets saved once analyzed).

Edit2: Here's the *referring* code.  I've added all of the CFRelease(fileURL), but it still leaks:

```
uint_t aubio_sink_apple_audio_open(aubio_sink_apple_audio_t *s) {

  if (s->samplerate == 0 || s->channels == 0) return AUBIO_FAIL;

  AudioStreamBasicDescription clientFormat;
  memset(&clientFormat, 0, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
  clientFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
  clientFormat.mSampleRate       = (Float64)(s->samplerate);
  clientFormat.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
  clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = s->channels;
  clientFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = sizeof(short) * 8;
  clientFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
  clientFormat.mBytesPerFrame    = clientFormat.mBitsPerChannel * clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame / 8;
  clientFormat.mBytesPerPacket   = clientFormat.mFramesPerPacket * clientFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
  clientFormat.mReserved         = 0;

  AudioFileTypeID fileType = kAudioFileWAVEType;
  CFURLRef fileURL = getURLFromPath(s->path);
  bool overwrite = true;
  OSStatus err = noErr;
  err = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(fileURL, fileType, &clientFormat, NULL,
     overwrite ? kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile : 0, &s->audioFile);
  if (err) {
    char_t errorstr[20];
    AUBIO_ERR("sink_apple_audio: error when trying to create %s with "
        "ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL (%s)\n", s->path,
        getPrintableOSStatusError(errorstr, err));
    goto beach;
  }
  if (createAubioBufferList(&s->bufferList, s->channels, s->max_frames * s->channels)) {
    AUBIO_ERR("sink_apple_audio: error when creating buffer list for %s, "
        "out of memory? \n", s->path);
    goto beach;
  }

  //added release code
  CFRelease(fileURL);
  return AUBIO_OK;

beach:
  //added release code
  CFRelease(fileURL);
  return AUBIO_FAIL;
}
```

EDIT3: Here's a screenshot
[image: Instrument panel]

EDIT4: The original solution actually works, XCode refused to load the new version of my framework even though I kept recompiling it.  So, I had to purge all references of the framework - including scrubbing the Build info pages - and re-add the "fixed" version.

Comment: Run the analyzer on your code. Does it report any issues with your code? If so, fix the issues and then see if you still have the leak.

Comment: Hey rmaddy, I just performed an analysis on my project.  The only errors that come up revolve around cell prototype ids and splash screens (due to my incomplete storyboarding).  My project is still very incomplete and small, and I figured I should perform a 'code cleanup' and review before continuing on the next big chunk.  That's how I discovered this very small memory leak

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator or a real device? Only do leak testing on real devices.

Comment: Real device, iPhone 5S with 8.3. Also added a screenshot of the stack trace.  Could the error lay with "ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL", a method provided by Apple?... hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaking the returned `CFURLRef` created with `CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath`.

You should rename the function from `getURLFromPath` to `createURLFromPath` to indicate that ownership of the returned `CFURLRef` is being passed on to the caller. Then any code that calls the method is responsible for releasing the `CFURLRef` when done with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help; I've added CFRelease(fileURL) in the code that calls it, but am still experiencing the links.  I've added the calling code to my original question.

Comment: Hey rmaddy! Your solution did end up working; despite my builds and cleans, XCode kept caching an old version of the framework.  I ended up having to remove all references to the library (including deleting folder references from the framework search paths), and readding a new one.

What was neat, however, is that the framework was also upgraded from .41 to .42 so I got a free bug-fix upgrade as well!